# Django Model append phrase to app_label

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am doing some external integrations to save data to Django models. The integrations are taking some time. So I would like to create some temporary duplicate models. I create data into these temporary models. After finishing the process, I transfer my data to the actual model. By doing this I don't give any downtime on the system.

```
class MyModelAbstract(models.Model):
    my_field = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ...

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class MyModel(MyModelAbstract):
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class MyModelTemp(MyModelAbstract):
    pass
```

If my apps name is `my_app` than the table names are becoming `my_app_mymodel` and `my_app_mymodeltemp`. I would like to name it like `my_app_tmp_mymodeltemp`. I can accomplish this with following:

```
class MyModelTemp(MyModelAbstract):
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'my_app_tmp'
```

But I don't want to write `app_label` statically. If I change the name, I do not want to alter `app_label` by hand. I want to specify it like `app_label = '%s_tmp' % app_label` but I cannot access current app's label in the inner Meta class.

Furthermore I can handle this with creating new meta class for this case. I am looking for a simpler approach.

Comment: AFAIK, this cannot be done because you will need to have migrations to change the actual table names and migrations cannot be dynamic

Comment: I don't want to change migration behaviour. I would like to alter app_label during new class creation before registering model. Thus it won't affect migrations.

Comment: a better explaination of that comment is needed

Comment: What I want is to change `app_label` with using its original value coming from `app_config`. I want to do it by model, not all models in a module. Since app_label is set at `Meta` class, I cannot access original value in the `Meta` class.

Answer (score 1):

> If my apps name is my_app than the table names are becoming my_app_mymodel and my_app_mymodeltemp

**Comment**

`app_label` is used when `Model` is outside of `INSTALLED_APPS`. Now your intention(assuming) you need another table named prefix `tmp`. For that you need `db_table`. We can do it on the fly by putting this snippet under each model.

```
from django.db import connection

Model._meta.db_table = Model._meta.db_table+ "_tmp"
with connection.schema_editor() as schema:
    schema.create_model(Model)
```

Comment: My app is in `INSTALLED_APPS`, I am normally happy with the table naming. But for some tables, I would like to distinguish from the others but not losing the app_label. I want `tmp` to be between app label and model name. This way I will see them in order, while managing the product. I am not sure but it seems to me that what you suggest could break my migrations!?

Comment: AFAIK it will not.Anyway keep migrations files in git or version control.